# Installing Python 2.7 on Debian 12 in a virtualenv (or other options)

Tags: debian, python

I know that Python 2.7 was EOL'd years ago, but I still have a sprawling code base which I I have to maintain that uses it.  I hope to get it upgraded in the coming months, but it's not fully in my control.

Recently I upgraded my system to Debian trixie, the current testing branch. But after the upgrade I discovered that Debian bookworm onwards [does not include Python 2 at all](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=34227760).  I understand that I may need to set it up in a container, or in some kind of virtualenv.  I am not a professional coder and am not really familiar with containers, so the latter option would be preferable.

So my questions would be:

1. Would it be possible to set up Python 2.7 in a virtualenv for the purposes of the code I have to maintain?
2. If so, what would be the best way to get the binaries?  I know I can attempt to compile it from source, but is there any other reliable way to obtain them?  I have  found binaries on [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org), but it is not clear if that would work for installing in a virtualenv.
3. If I have to use a container, does that mean I need to set up an entire new install of Debian in that container?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the easiest way to address this is to install [pypy](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html).  For the moment Pypy still offers an interpreter for Python 2.7, and it seems to be self-contained such that you can just download it and symlink to it without mucking with your system.  I'm surprised very few people seem to mention this option.

Of course, if you are in the same pickle as I am, I'd suggest doing this soon, since one can expect that Pypy will drop support soon too.